# How to get track execution duration for each activity in datafactory

Tags: azure-data-factory

*There is pipeline pl_main and had for-each activity.
For each activity calls another child pipeline there had three activities(lookup,notebook,lookup).
Look up activity calls insert/update for log table.
Question is how can i get total execution duration for-each activity.So that i can get it throughput for records.
My moto is to pass total duration and log into delta lake table
*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution to get the execution duration of `ForEach` activity is to use variables and assign the current time before and after the execution of the `ForEach` activity. The following is a detailed demonstration of how you can do this.

- I have a pipeline which has `Get Metadata` activity, `ForEach` activity (takes items from the childitems of get metadata activity) and inside foreach I have `Copy Data` activity.

[image]

- To this pipeline, I have added `Set Variable` activity before and after `ForEach` activity as shown below.

[image]

- In `get_start_time` activity I have created **start_time** variable (String), and in `get_end_time` activity I have created **end_time** variable (String).

[image]

- I have given `start_time` value as `@utcnow()` which returns the current timestamp value as a string. I have done the same for `end_time` as well.

[image]

- When I debug the pipeline, it succeeds and returns the required output. The following is the image of each activity run.

[image]

- The value returned for `start_time`:

[image]

- The value returned for `end_time`:

[image]

- Since you want to log the `ForEach` activity duration to delta lake table, you can make use of these variables `start_time and end_time`. When inserting into the table, you can use `DATEDIFF()` function (returns difference between two timestamps in seconds). Refer to this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to understand more about **DATEDIFF** function.